# Python reshaping 1D array into 2D array by 'rows' or 'columns'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to control how array.reshape() populates the new array.  For example

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
## array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
##   [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
##   [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

but what I would like to be able to is populate the array columnwise with something like:

```
a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3, 'columnwise')
## array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
##   [ 1,  4,  7,  10],
##   [ 2,  5, 8, 11]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.transpose`.

```
import numpy as np

print(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3).transpose())
```

Output:

```
[[0 3 6]
 [1 4 7]
 [2 5 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a transpose of the original matrix, you will get your desired effect.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(6).reshape(3,3).tranpose()
```

OR

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape(3,3).T
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [22]:  np.arange(12).reshape(3,4, order='F')                                                        
Out[22]: 
array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
       [ 1,  4,  7, 10],
       [ 2,  5,  8, 11]])
```